# Override a method call so it is not called under specific situations

Tags: c#, wpf

I apologize for the weird topic wording.

I have two Date pickers, a Duration textbox only accepting numeric values, and two methods for the SelectedDateChanged along with the Text_TextChanged.

What I am trying to do is what MS Project does with their Start Date/End Date/Duration (if anyone has any knowledge with it) But basically, a user can enter 2 of the 3 and it will populate the the other one accordingly. So if I enter 3 in textbox (days) and I choose 12/10/2013 in my End Date `DatePicker` my 2 objects should say startdate - `12/10/2013` End Date - `12/13/2013` text 3

Here is my code behind for the 2 datePicker Methods.

```
    private void DatePickerEndDate1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerEndDate1.ToString()))
            newEndDate = DateTime.Parse(DatePickerEndDate1.ToString());
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerEndDate1.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerStartDate1.ToString()))
        {
            if (DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate < DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate)
            {
                DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate = DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate;
                DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate = originalStartDate;
            }

            TimeSpan differenceBetweenStartandEndDate = newEndDate.Subtract(newStartDate);
            TextDuration.Text = differenceBetweenStartandEndDate.Days.ToString();
        }
        else if (DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate != null && DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate == null)
        {
            DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate = newEndDate;
            DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate = newEndDate.AddDays(taskLength);
        }
    }

    private void DatePickerStartDate1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerStartDate1.ToString()))
            newStartDate = DateTime.Parse(DatePickerStartDate1.ToString());
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerEndDate1.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DatePickerStartDate1.ToString()))
        {
            if (DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate > DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate)
            {
                DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate = DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate;
                DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate = originalEndDate;
            }


            TimeSpan differenceBetweenStartandEndDate = newEndDate.Subtract(newStartDate);
            TextDuration.Text = differenceBetweenStartandEndDate.Days.ToString();
        }
        else if (DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate != null && DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate == null)
        {
            DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate = newEndDate;
            DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate = newEndDate.AddDays(taskLength);
        }

    }
```

I was debugging and realized my error came when I was resetting say DatePickerStartDate1 (for this instance)in the Else if method. And this would ReFire my DatePickerEndDate1 since it was being changed which would also call my TextDuration_TextChanged.

```
    private void TextDuration_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(int.TryParse(TextDuration.Text, out taskLength))

        if (DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate = newStartDate.AddDays(taskLength);
        }
        else if (DatePickerEndDate1.SelectedDate != null)
        {
            DatePickerStartDate1.SelectedDate = newEndDate.AddDays(taskLength);
        }
    }
```

which is firing that, it would reset my taskLength back to 0 and ultimately setting all the dates to `12/10/2013` since it never added the 3 days.

Now I was wondering if I could write a line of code that would NOT call that method if and only if I was in that else if?

Comment: In the past, when there was absolutely no other option, I have resorted to setting flags to control the OnChanged event's behavior. Set 'myCall = true' when you're adjusting, check for 'myCall' in the OnChanged event, and reset it there if true.

Comment: Do a -= to remove the handler then add it back.  And why would you AddDays to start.

Comment: I should add, be careful going to flag route. It is liable to get very confusing quickly, and maybe become rather unreadable.

Comment: I tried doing the bool myCall and it worked but I didnt tweak it enough to make it work everytime and it also breaks my other methods that set the date if you just use the datepickers. Im going to give the -= remove a shot now though that seems a bit simpler. Thanks alot for feedback though

@Blam - I AddDays to start since i always want the earlier date in the start date and later date int he end date. and the duration just counts the days between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to do business logic in the UI and it is messy
Not only messy but fails if you change date with something other than the datepicker
Binding, get, set, and NotifyPropertyChanged are your friends

```
private DateTime? date1;
private DateTime? date2;
private Int32? taskLength;

public DateTime? Date1
{
    get { return date1; }
    set 
    {
        if (date1 == value) return;
        date1 = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Date1");
        if (taskLength != null && date1 != null)
        {  
            date2 = date1.AddDays(taskLength);  
            // by calling the backing property you don't hit the set 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Date2");
            // anything bound will call the get 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I've dealt with this problem in the past is with an "ignore events" flag. The code would look something like this:

```
public class MyForm
{
   private bool _disableEvents = false;

   private void Event1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (_disableEvents)
         return;

      _disableEvents = true;
      try
      {
         // do stuff that triggers Event2
      }
      finally
      {
         _disableEvents = false;
      }
   }

   private void Event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (_disableEvents)
         return;

      _disableEvents = true;
      try
      {
         // do stuff that triggers Event1
      }
      finally
      {
         _disableEvents = false;
      }
   }
}
```